# Binding parent container props to content child control in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, data-binding

**Example:**

```
<UserControl x:Name="userControl"
    <StackPanel x:Name="container" Margin="0">
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=SettingValue, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

UserControl contains `SettingValue` dependency property, TextBox doesn't, 
so this example won't work.

I could've done this if I had `AncestorType`, like in WPF:

```
RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControlType}
```

Is there any possibility to bind to UserControl.SettingValue property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try the following? Use the `ElementName` source (the syntax might be a bit off).

```
 <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=SettingValue, ElementName=userControl"/>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/729689/binding-silverlight-usercontrol-custom-properties-to-its-elements/2711967#2711967

Answer (score 0):

The answer I've found here:

[Binding Silverlight UserControl custom properties to its' elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/729689/binding-silverlight-usercontrol-custom-properties-to-its-elements/2711967#2711967)